# Stuck weblogic thread when starting managed server using node manager

Tags: weblogic

We are receiving the following error -- a thread gets stuck -- when we try to start any managed server in our cluster via the admin console in Weblogic 10.3.2. The managed servers used to start up fine last week. The only difference between this week and last week is that our VM (virtual machine) was powered down for a week. We started it back up and tried to bring up the managed servers and we get this error. My inkling is that something changed in the physical host or VM configuration (external to our operating system), but I have been told that none of that had been changed.

We are running WebLogic on Windows Server 2008.

Any ideas?

```
  <Jan 3, 2011 6:10:45 PM GMT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy fo
r "228" seconds working on the request "weblogic.kernel.WorkManagerWrapper$1@291d575", which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "120" second
s. Stack trace:
        jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(Native Method)
        jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:32)
        java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
        java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:159)
        java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:85)
        com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readFragment(Unknown Source)
        com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.read(Unknown Source)
        com.certicom.io.InputSSLIOStreamWrapper.read(Unknown Source)
        sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
        sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
        sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
        java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
        java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
        java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
        java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
        weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.checkResponse(NMServerClient.java:287)
        weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.checkResponse(NMServerClient.java:312)
        weblogic.nodemanager.client.NMServerClient.start(NMServerClient.java:101)
        weblogic.nodemanager.mbean.StartRequest.start(StartRequest.java:75)
        weblogic.nodemanager.mbean.StartRequest.execute(StartRequest.java:47)
        weblogic.kernel.WorkManagerWrapper$1.run(WorkManagerWrapper.java:63)
        weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us, we received this error because our Weblogic instances, which are configured with an Active Directory provider could not communicate with Active Directory. Once we fixed the communication issue, this problem went away.